# PrimeFaces: layout fullPage set as"false" is causing footer to dissapear

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

Maybe its another newbie issue I'm having here today, but I can't find the solution. Tried some CSS tricks but they didn't give the result I wanted.

I decided to set the layout fullPage property as false because I didnt want any scrollbar annoying me and when I changed to false I got the results I wanted.

But it caused the footer to dissapear... it's not showing in my page anymore.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Nothing special in my code but here it is:

```
<p:layout fullPage="false">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="170" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">  
       //Content
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">    
       //Content
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">                 
       //Content             
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
       //Content
    </p:layoutUnit>  

</p:layout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug in primeface, until it fixed try

```
<p:layoutUnit styleClass="layoutUnitCenter" position="center"  closable="false" >
     <ui:insert name="content" />
     <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

basically you are including the footer in the center content, regardless of center content size the footer is going to display right below it. It looks nice

Answer (score 0):

As for your first issue with the scrollbar you could remove it by adding css to your layout style:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .ui-layout-center {                    
            overflow-x:hidden !important;
            overflow-y:hidden !important;
        }

        .ui-layout-center .ui-layout-unit-content {
            overflow-x:hidden !important;
            overflow-y:hidden !important;
        }     
    </style>
```

As for the second problem did you try addind a fixed style for your layput component? For example:

```
<p:layout style="width:400px;height:200px">
...
</p:layout>
```